# how to get a single feature vector from SIFT descriptor

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to use SIFT descriptor to describe features that I got before.

the thing is, when I am using features image with SIFT descriptor the result is nx128 . where n is a different number for each different images. I know SIFT using a key-point description and for that reason there is a difference in the dimension of rows. but is there any way to get a single feature vector (1x128).

Regards

Comment: `B` is an image, already loaded into a matrix. Why would you need to read it?

Comment: `'B'` is not a valid filename. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: you want `C=B` .....

Comment: Ok, I need to crop an image and then read the cropped part and put it as an input for a system.  I already cropped the image so should I directly put the cropped part into the system or read it and then put it as input.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "put it as input for a system", but if `B` is the result of cropping `A`, then `B` is already an image. Do `imshow(B);`

Comment: Do you want to do image subtraction ?

Comment: It doesnt matther what you do to the image, the result is just an iamge. Actually an image is a matrix. Absolutely any matrix that you can imagine. you can `imshow(matrix)` or `imshow(matrix,[])` **anything**

Comment: I meant by system, for example I will take the cropped image and use it as input for descriptor, so should I directly put it in or read it before that?

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure without seeing your actual code, but I'm going to say directly put it in. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your comments, an appropriate solution would be:

```
A = imread('Car.jpg');

% loads the image with a crop tool, select the region to be cropped
B = imcrop(A);
close

% Displays the cropped region
figure, imshow(B);
```

Comment: thanks for response, I used the same way to crop the image .. for your example I want to put (B) in this function: H = HOG (B), when I run this function there is always error but when I used the same function with an image that been read by imread , so it will be ok

Comment: dont know what is the error!!

Comment: @Mammo Neither do we. You don't show us the actual code you're running, you don't show us the output you're getting, and you expect us to guess what the problem is. My mind reading skills are not quite that good.

Comment: @ beaker, sorry for that .. it is as simple like this code:                          Im = imread ('airplane.jpg');
Im = rgb2gray (Im);
%imshow(Im);
rect = [75 68 180 200];
CC = imcrop (Im,rect);
%imshow (CC);
H = HOG (CC);'

Comment: I sorry the code is like rubbish but I did not know how to manage it here .. BTW the code is working now because there was an error in the position of the function since it was out side the loop.  thanks so much

Comment: @Mammo You can't format code in comments. The proper way is to edit your original question and add the code there.

Comment: @beaker, sorry again I edited now in the work space . thanks so much

Comment: @Mammo The code looks fine, apart from the function HOG. You should try this on different images and if you still can't find the error debug line by line.

Comment: yes thanks, the code is fine now the error was about using HOG function in unsuitable place in the code .. Regards

Comment: @Mammo you could always express your thanks by check marking the answer and up-voting comments :)